# DSE Solr - reducing netty_client_request_timeout

Tags: solr, timeout, netty, datastax

If my client is running Solr search queries with a socket timeout of 1 second, is there any reason I would want netty_client_request_timeout in dse.yaml to be more than 1000?

Wouldn't reducing it take some load off the cluster by letting queries be discontinued that the client gave up on?

I guess there might be the benefit of leaving it higher than the client's timeout so that writes can perhaps complete after the client's timed out, since the client doesn't care about the response in that case.

Answer (score 0):

`netty_client_request_timeout` is the cumulative time that the coordinator of a distributed request will wait for the responses from its shard queries. If you have a hard, client-side time-out of 1 second (and that was determined by taking into account your actual query performance patterns), pushing `netty_client_request_timeout` much higher than that probably doesn't make sense. Remember though that this doesn't necessarily stop the execution of queries on the shards! If you want to do that, you might want to investigate the query parameter [timeAllowed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-ThetimeAllowedParameter).

Finally, if you are indeed using DSE Search, I strongly suggest you insert/update using CQL and the native driver, as this simplifies the write/indexing path on the server side.